# Using onclick with javascript function, call js var in parameters

Tags: php, javascript, html, onclick

Hey guys a bit stuck here. Ill first start with showing you the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var Stanley = "Text here";
function TextLooper(Alien)
{
var myArray = Alien.split("");
var loopTimer;
var changeLetter = function () 
{
    if(myArray.length > 0) 
    {
        document.getElementById("TypingStanley").innerHTML += myArray.shift();
    } 
    else 
    {
        clearTimeout(loopTimer); 
    }
}
setInterval(changeLetter, 70);
};
function InfoBoxClick(id, visibility,AlienVar) 
{
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility; 
    TextLooper(AlienVar);
}
</script>
```

Thats my javascript and i use a href with onlick which is below;

```
<a href="#Aliens-Stanley" onclick="InfoBoxClick('StanleyInfo','block','Stanley');">LinkName</a>
```

I am trying for the third parameter of the function InfoBoxClick() to be the var named Stanley mentioned in the javascript, but i cant seem to do it, anyone know what i need to do???

Comment: Your code seems to be fine: http://jsfiddle.net/nivas/zewyU/

Comment: @Nivas the code is not working there, as you see it says the word stanley, but in that code it should say text here.  I have now sorted this problem, my next problem is if i click more than once it calls the function multiple times and alters the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to reference `Stanley` as a variable in the onclick:

```
InfoBoxClick('StanleyInfo','block',Stanley);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e44yS/)

Just a friendly comment on style, variables should be *lowercase*, classes and constants should be *CapitalCase* and *UPPERCASE* respectively. It's only a convention, but will help other javascript developers understand your code.

Comment: That works perfect thank you, ill accept this. One more question, is it possible to tell it to only run the script once as getting a bug when i click on the link again

Answer (score 0):

bcoz in js one parameters is always hidden like (this),

if you want to pass 3 parameters then dont send 3. sent 4 parameters and 1st one is (this)

```
<a href="#Aliens-Stanley" onclick="InfoBoxClick(this,'StanleyInfo','block','Stanley');">LinkName</a>
```

and yore function write

```
function InfoBoxClick(e,id, visibility,AlienVar) 
{
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility; 
    TextLooper(AlienVar);
}
```

in this 1st parameters e mens event of the action eg(onclick,......)

Comment: doesnt seem to answer my question, but what is the benefit of putting this? and the reason for it?

Comment: if you dont put "this" and your last parameter i.e "3rd" automatically convert in "this", "this" mens even name

Comment: first run puting with "this" and check it, then tell me